# Will iptables rules continue to work if an interface has been deleted and created again?

Tags: iptables

My server connects to some strange resources via OpenVPN, and every time the OpenVPN client starts up, an `ovpn` interface is brought up.

I want to expose only selected ports (say, MySQL) to this interface, so I have this rule in my iptables:

```
iptables -A INPUT -i ovpn -p tcp --dport 3306 -j ACCEPT
```

However, because the OpenVPN client can disconnect and reconnect without intervention, the link ID (as shown by `ip link show ovpn`) can change.

Will the above iptables rule continue to work after the link disappears and appears again (with a different ID)?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Yes it will continue to work, because *iptables* doesn't use the interface's index but is doing a string comparison with the current interface's name when evaluating the `-i`/`--in-interface` parameter. Actually it appears to be [always evaluated](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.19/source/net/ipv4/netfilter/ip_tables.c#L62), even when the parameter is not provided, but the [inlined function](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.19/source/include/linux/netfilter/x_tables.h#L400) is quite optimized.

By contrast, *nftables* (the current candidate successor to *iptables*) offers two different expressions: `iifname`: the direct equivalent of `-i`, comparing the current name, and `iif` comparing the interface index, which would cause a problem in your use case. When *iptables* is translated into *nftables* (either using [*iptables-translate*](https://manpages.debian.org/iptables/iptables-translate.8) or [*iptables-nft*](https://manpages.debian.org/buster/iptables-nft.8) for the newer iptables-over-kernel-nftables API), `-i` gets translated to `iifname` as expected for compatibility.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, it will. Rules don't get deleted when referenced interface is deleted.

More on that, there are wildcard rules, for example you can specify "any pppX interface" with the match `-i ppp+` or `-o ppp+`. There is no interface with that name at all, so it can't reference anything. But if there will be traffic involving ppp2 interface, such rule will immediately apply.

In general, it doesn't matter, was the rule created before interface appeared or after that.

Comment: So rules are matched by name, not by link ID, right?